VBA for transfer emails from Outlook app to excel
I need your help guys if you can. I am new to VBA so I am still learning and my code is probably not powerful but I would like to bring it to life. It works, but in a different way than I expected. I am sharing with you my excel VBA code to receive emails from Outlook. When I start Excel and Outlook and run the vba code I get an error on this line =>
Set Folder = Outlook.Session.Folders(MailboxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name).Folders(subFolderName)

but when I close and re-open outlook it works and gets all the information into the table up to 30 days back and then I get the message "object doesn't support this property method" code438.. in this line =>
Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 1) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime

FYI.. I have a default email address set up in outlook which is mine and a shared email address that other ppl also use and there is a sub file in the shared email address. so I'm trying to get the email from the shared email address and subfolder only.
Here is the code:
Sub GetEmailsInTo()

    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim Pst_Folder_Name As String
    Dim MailboxName As String
    Dim subFolderName As String
    
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
'Mailbox or PST Main Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
MailboxName = "shareemails@info.com"

'Mailbox Folder or PST Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox"

'subfolder name
subFolderName = "important"

Set Folder = Outlook.Session.Folders(MailboxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name).Folders(subFolderName)
If Folder = "" Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Data in Input"
    GoTo end_lbl1:
End If
    
Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Clear

'Date
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-409]ddd dd/mm/yy;@"
Range("A2:A500").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 13
Range("A2:A500").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
Range("A2:A500").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    
   Range("A1:E1").Select
 With Selection
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .RowHeight = 55
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

    Range("B2:B500").Select
With Selection
    .WrapText = True
    .ColumnWidth = 16
    .Rows.AutoFit
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    
End With

    Range("C2:C500").Select
    With Selection
    .WrapText = True
    .ColumnWidth = 40
    .Rows.AutoFit
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    
End With

    Range("D2:D500").Select
With Selection
    .WrapText = True
    .ColumnWidth = 170
    .Rows.AutoFit
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    
End With

 Range("E2:E500").Select
With Selection
    .WrapText = True
    .ColumnWidth = 50
    .Rows.AutoFit
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    
End With

    'Rad Through each Mail and export the details to Excel for Email Archival
Sheets(1).Activate

For iRow = 2 To Folder.Items.Count
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 2).Select
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 1) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 2) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderName
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 3) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 4) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).To
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 5) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).CC
    
Next iRow
    
    MsgBox "Email import complete"


    
end_lbl1:
    
End Sub


Try Set Folder = ns.Folders(MailboxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name).Folders(subFolderName)

Edit the post to add the first error.

Break Set Folder into three parts to see where the first error occurs.

The expectation is one question per post. You can ask a new question about the folder. Set Folder = ns.Folders(MailboxName) and Set Folder = Folder.Folders(Pst_Folder_Name) and Set Folder = Folder.Folders(subFolderName). Put in the error and on which line it occurs.

Non-mailitems may not have a mailitem property. As well iRow is one more than the item index.
Option Explicit

Sub GetEmailsInToV2()

    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
    
    Dim mailboxFolder As Outlook.folder
    Dim inboxFolder As Outlook.folder
    Dim subFolder As Outlook.folder
    
    Dim mailboxName As String
    Dim inboxName As String
    Dim subFolderName As String
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    'Mailbox Name as displayed in your Outlook Session)
    mailboxName = "shareemails@info.com"
    
    inboxName = "Inbox"
    
    'subfolder name
    subFolderName = "important"
    
    ' No attempt to address unknown error referencing the subfolder
    Set mailboxFolder = ns.Folders(mailboxName)
    Set inboxFolder = mailboxFolder.Folders(inboxName)
    Set subFolder = inboxFolder.Folders(subFolderName)
    
    Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Clear
    
    'Date
    With Columns("A:A")
        .NumberFormat = "[$-409]ddd dd/mm/yy;@"
        .ColumnWidth = 13
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    
    With Range("B:B")
        .WrapText = True
        .ColumnWidth = 16
        .Rows.AutoFit
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    
    With Range("C:C")
        .WrapText = True
        .ColumnWidth = 40
        .Rows.AutoFit
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    
    With Range("D:D")
        .WrapText = True
        .ColumnWidth = 170
        .Rows.AutoFit
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    End With
    
    With Range("E:E")
        .WrapText = True
        .ColumnWidth = 50
        .Rows.AutoFit
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    End With
    
    With Range("A1:E1")
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .RowHeight = 55
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    'Read each mail and export the details to Excel for Email Archival
    'Sheets(1).Activate
    
    For iRow = 2 To subFolder.Items.Count + 1
    
        With subFolder.Items.Item(iRow - 1)
        
            ' Non-mailitems may not have mailitem properties
            If .Class = olMail Then
                'Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 2).Select
                Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 1) = .ReceivedTime
                Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 2) = .SenderName
                Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 3) = .Subject
                Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 4) = .To
                Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 5) = .CC
                
                ' Clear requires an entry in column E
                If Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 5) = "" Then
                    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 5) = "-"
                End If
                
            Else
                Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 1) = "-"  ' Clear requires an entry in column A
                Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 3) = "Not a mailitem."
                Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 5) = "-"   ' Clear requires an entry in column E
            End If
            
        End With
        
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Email import complete"

End Sub


thanks for your help. This code works that the message import is complete but the list is empty. With some small modification this code will work for me but I already found solutions that work for me from "Black cat" user.. Thanks anyway

Your code works for mails. Problem can be that there are items in the folder which are not mails. Filter it something like this:
iRow=2
For iRowAct = 1 To Folder.Items.Count
  If Folder.Items.Item(iRowAct).Class = olMail Then
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 2).Select
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 1) = Folder.Items.Item(iRowAct).ReceivedTime
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 2) = Folder.Items.Item(iRowAct).SenderName
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 3) = Folder.Items.Item(iRowAct).Subject
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 4) = Folder.Items.Item(iRowAct).To
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 5) = Folder.Items.Item(iRowAct).CC
    iRow = iRow + 1
  End If
Next iRowAct

